# Microsoft Graph: unable to use a URL embeddable in an iframe

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using the Microsoft Graph REST API version v1.0, my current plan is Microsoft 365 Business Basic and I am unable to use a embeddable URL from a PowerPoint file in the website's iframe and I do not receive any error returns from the Microsoft Graph API, I just can't see.

Endpoint: POST /me/drive/items/{itemId}/preview

Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-preview?view=graph-rest-1.0

[image: Cannot view the pptx file]

Comment: I don't think that the error is related to Microsoft Graph. Try to google the error message. https://www.google.com/search?q=looks+like+this+file+doesn%27t+have+a+preview&oq=looks+like+this+file+doesn%27t+have+a+preview

Comment: Does it throws any Graph error? If yes please do share.